# how to pass json encode to javascript in PHP?

Tags: php, json, urlencode, urldecode

i want to encode a json because it contains special characters

I try to use simple urlencode but it doesn't work. 
When I print the variable in alert on the js is empty

```
$sql="select name,surname from agents";
$res = $conn->query($sql);
while($row = $res->fetch_assoc()) 
{
   $rows[] = $row;
}
$json = json_encode($rows);
echo urlencode($json);
```

Comment: Change `$rows[] = $row` to `$rows[] = json_encode($row)`

Comment: I try but it print array [false,false,false,false]

Comment: what do you get in `$json`?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by doing this? If you are trying to create a javascript variable then you don't need to do this. You can just use `var agents = <?=$json?>;`

Comment: @RedBottle $json = [false,false,false,false]

Comment: @frobinsonj it is php

Comment: I know lol. Your title says you want to "pass json encode to javascript"?

Comment: Yes i want to pass json to javascript but json is empty

Comment: @hamid What you receive in $rows , print_r($rows);

Comment: @suhaspandit i receive an array

Comment: @hamid I gues urlencode is not needed you can simply use json_encode(), this link might help you : https://www.dyn-web.com/tutorials/php-js/json/array.php

Answer (score 1):

If you want to json encode you need to set response header to application/json and unicode escaped

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($rows, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show the contents of a json encoded array in javascript, you first need to [decode](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_parse.asp) it:

`var array = JSON.parse(json_string);`

Next you can iterate over the array and display it's contents.